# On a problem of Erdős about continued fractions and Liouville numbers

Tags: continued-fractions, liouville-numbers

In 1938, Erdős and Mahler raised the following question:

> Let $\xi$ be a real number such that $(p_n/q_n)_n$ are convergents of its continued fraction. If there exists a subsequence $(p_{n_j}/q_{n_j})_j$ of the convergents such that $P(p_{n_j}q_{n_j})\leq M$ for all $j$ (where $P(m)$ denotes the greatest prime factor of $m$), then $\xi$ is a Liouville number.

Erdős and Mahler proved the existence of numbers with this property.

I would like to ask you if it is possible to construct this subsequence with the property that $n_j-n_{j-1}\leq k$ for some constant $k$ and all $j$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you link to the article where they prove existence, and tell us if their proof is constructive or not?

Comment: @guest : see the last sentence of math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1939-12.pdf , and all you can find on the subject is in https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?espv=2&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&biw=1280&bih=852&dpr=1&ion=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&cites=12876755108838559848